# Perl - reading file into multidimension array

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, trim

I am hoping someone can assist me, I am fairly new to Perl, I have looked and found some sample scripts but cannot get this to work.

I have input file that is generated by a SQL query:

```
0050560A49871EEBAE9D90FC8C9E1808         d:\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              060606                                           812
aaaaemsmf61wbjmqmiaaezroku2u3            d:\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              060606                                           817
aaaaemsmf61wbjmqmiaaezroku2u3            d:\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              060606                                           817
aaaacodrditwbjvwwqaaaaboku2u3            d:\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              060606                                           820
aaaacodrditwbjvwwqaaaaboku2u3            d:\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              060606                                           820

(5 rows affected)
```

Using the following code I am trying to read the contents into a multidimensional array :

```
my $data;
my $fields = {};
read_folder();
for ($i = 0; $i < $input_file_number; $i++){
    my $file =  "./extracted/$sql_scripts[$i]";
    printf "file = $sql_scripts[$i]\n";
    open($data, '<:encoding(UTF-8)',$file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

    while (<$data>)
    {
        push @fields, [split/s+/];
    }
    print Dumper( @fields ), "\n\n"; 
}
```

However when I user the print Dumper command it shows that each line from the file has been put into the array but has not split the lines when a space occurs, am i using the push @fields, [split/s+/]; command wrong ?  In additon I would like to remove the whitespace betweeen each value on the line, when added to the array.

Any help will be much appricated

Comment: It looks like you think `my $fields` and `@fields` are the same variable. They are not. `@fields` is a global variable. You should always use `use strict; use warnings` to prevent making easily avoidable mistakes and typos. You should also not declare `my $data` outside the loop, preferably declare it directly in the `open`: `open my $data, ...`. Also, all of this code can (probably) be replaced with `perl -MData::Dumper -lane"push @fields, [ @F ]; END { print Dumper \@fields }" yourfiles*`

Answer (score 2):

The regex pattern `s+` matches one or more `s`, so the following is wrong:

```perl
push @fields, [ split /s+/ ];    # Short for: `split /s+/, $_, -1`
```

You want `\s+`: one or more whitespace character.

```perl
push @fields, [ split /\s+/ ];   # Short for: `split /\s+/, $_, -1`
```

Alternatively, you could pass a single space to `split`. This is a treated specially, and it's almost identical to using `\s+`. The only difference is that passing a single space causes the `split` to ignores leading whitespace in the input.

```perl
push @fields, [ split ];         # Short for: `split " ", $_, -1`
```

Answer (score -1):

Managed to figure it out, by changing the line

```
push @fields, [split/s+/];
```

to

```
push @fields,  [split " "];
```

I accomplish both the data being split by the values, and also the whitespace is removed

Comment: Well, splitting on a literal space `" "` is better in some cases (it strips leading whitespace), but also you had written `s+` (one or more of the character `"s"` ), instead of what you presumably wanted `\s+` (one or more of whitespace).

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that any future readers can learn from it.